# Aligning equation in \multirow

Tags: horizontal-alignment, multirow

I want to align this text.
For a calculation sheet I need a uniform input for repetitive use.

[image]

This is my code:

````
% Document Class
% **************************************************
\documentclass[
    paper=A4,                   %
    11pt,                       % font size
]{scrreprt}                     %

\RequirePackage{tabularx}       % table features
\RequirePackage{textcomp}       % different symbols
\usepackage{tikz}               % check marks
\usepackage{amssymb}            % for calculations
\usepackage{datatool}           % tools to load and manipulate data
\usepackage{array,multirow}     % for calculations

\begin{document}

\newenvironment{conditions*}
    {\par\vspace{\abovedisplayskip}\noindent
    \tabularx{\columnwidth}{
    @{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{4cm}
    >{$}p{0.7cm}<{$}
    @{${}{}$}
    >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{6cm}|
    >{$}p{0.7cm}<{$}
    @{${}={}$}
    >{\color{blue}$}m{1.2cm}<{$}
    >{$}X<{$}
    }}{\endtabularx\par\vspace{\belowdisplayskip}}
   
\def\s{454}
\def\k{0.00394}

\begin{conditions*}
Spacing of stiffeners
        & 
        & 
        & s
        & \s
        & \mathrm{mm} \\
Factor
        & 
        & 
        & k
        & \k
        & \mathrm{mm} \\
\multirow{2}{*}{Required thickness} &
\multirow{2}{*}{$t_{req}$}
\multirow{2}{*}{
        $\begin{aligned}[t]
        & = k \times  s \\
        & = \k \times  \s \\
        & = 1.78876
        \end{aligned}$}
        & & \multicolumn{3}{l}{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l} \\[-1em]
        [1]~{Chapter 11.1} \\[0em]
        \\[0em]
        \end{tabular}} \\ 
        & & & t_{req}
        & 1.78876
        & \mathrm{mm} \\
\end{conditions*}

\end{document} ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the optional alignment `[t]` to the front of all your `\multirow` commands:

```
\multirow[t]{2}{*}{Required thickness} & 
\multirow[t]{2}{*}{$t_{req}$}
\multirow[t]{2}{*}{
    $\begin{aligned}[t]
    & = k \times  s \\
    & = \k \times  \s \\
    & = 1.78876
    \end{aligned}$}
```

[image]